# Unity3D android USB communication

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, usb

I have an android app (made in Unity) and I want to receive data from usb cable (which is plugged in my pc)

Please some ideas?

My first idea was that I have an app (in android studio which creates the communication and then sends some data to unity with player settings).

I found out that System.IO.Ports doesn't work for android so I need your help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the best way I can think of to create TCP connection between your computer and app and use that TCP connection to actually send and receive data. If you are interested I can guide you in the direction how to achieve it.

Edit:
You can create a TCP listener in your unity project something like this:-

```
    int port = 8181;
    TcpListener listener = null;

    public void Awake()

    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(Listen());
    }

    private IEnumerator Listen()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port); 
        // start listening
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
    }
    public void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        // Call EndGetContext to complete the asynchronous operation.
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        //do your response-handling logic here
        listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
    }
```

Load this game object at your first start scene.
Than simply create a Java project in eclispe and connect using Socket to the running server.

Something like this:

```
    private Socket _socket = null;

    public void conenct()
    {
        _socket = new Socket(deviceIpAddress, SERVER_PORT);
    }

    public JSONObject read()
    {
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (_socket.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        _socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try
        {
            for (int b = 0; ((b = inFromServer.read()) >= 0);)
            {
                // Break on New Line character
                if (b == NEW_LINE.charAt(0))
                {
                    break;
                }
                responseStrBuilder.append((char)b);
            }
            // Unity Server Ack response on socket connection
            if (responseStrBuilder.length() == 0)
            {
                responseStrBuilder.append("{}");
            }

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
              return (jsonObject);

    }

    public void write(String msg)
    {
        PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(_socket.getOutputStream()));
        //send msg to server and include new line character
        outToServer.print(msg + NEW_LINE.charAt(0));
        outToServer.flush();
    }
```

You can use Read to read the data sent from unity and Write to send request to the unity server.
You can modify this according to what you need.

I did this in hurry so there might be some mistakes. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you!
If you can give me more details that will be great!

Comment: This Is not going to work, you cannot create a TCP socket over USB